# Controlling file mode of created target directory possible for rsync?

Tags: rsync, umask

I'm looking to control the file mode bits of the `directory-to-be-created` in the `rsync` command below:

```bsh
rsync -a ... <remote-user>@<remote-host>:/some/existing/path/directory-to-be-created/
```

As the name hopefully implies, that directory does not yet exist and `rsync` is expected to create it; which it dutifully does... *However*, near as I can tell it *always* does this adhering to the *<remote-host>*'s default `umask` and no `--chmod=...` incantation that I can fathom will make it do something else...

So is it possible at all to set the file mode with which a missing target directory will be created, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242135/how-to-force-rsync-to-create-destination-folder/14877351#14877351) set me on track of the [`--rsync-path=PROGRAM`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html#options) option:

> `--rsync-path=PROGRAM`
>
> Use this to specify what program is to be run on the remote machine to start-up rsync.  Often used when `rsync` is not in the default remote-shell’s path (e.g. `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync`).
>
> **Note that *`PROGRAM`* is run with the help of a shell, so it can be any program, script, or command sequence you’d care to run, so long as it does not corrupt the standard-in & standard-out that `rsync` is using to communicate.**
>
> One tricky example is to set a different default directory on the remote machine for use with the `--relative` option.  For instance:
>
> ```bsh
> rsync -avR --rsync-path="cd /a/b && rsync" host:c/d /e/
> ```

So it would appear that I can just do:

```bsh
rsync -a --rsync-path='umask 0022 && rsync' ...
```

... to pre-set the `umask` (or in fact, *any* required conditions) before the remote `rsync` gets invoked :-)

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` may not support that functionality natively, but you could use file systems [ACLs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) to ensure any newly created directory underneath `/some/existing/path/` has a specific set of permissions. For example:

```
$ setfacl -dm u::rwx,g::rx,o::r /some/existing/path/
```

Newly created directories underneath `/some/existing/path/` should now have the permissions `750`, manually or through `rsync`.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know about ACLs yet.  However, like expecting the system default `umask` to be, say, `0022`, this solution too depends on pre-made provisions at the receiving end... which - as was my experience, and direct cause for this question - can change... I was hoping for a  least-assumptions type of solution.

Comment: Right, not optimal, but useful for routine `rsync` operations to similar directory structures (something like backups).